# array required, but String found. ¿Por qué me sale este error?

Tags: javascript, java

En este caso quiero realizar una sustitución Polialfabética ingresando la llave junto con el mensaje y quiero obtener lo siguiente:
entrada: zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaholamundo
salida: sloznfmwl

mi función es la siguiente:

```
    public String cifrar(){

    String llave = texto.getText().substring(0,26);
    String mensaje = texto.getText().substring(26);
    String alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String textocifrado= "";

    for(int i=0; i<mensaje.length(); i++){
        
        textocifrado += llave[alfabeto(mensaje[i])];
    }
    textocdo.setText(textocifrado);
    return textocifrado; 
    }
```

y en la parte de

```
    textocifrado += llave[alfabeto(mensaje[i])];
```

me sale el error: "array required, but String found"

Comment: Mensaje[i] devuelve un carácter y tiene que ser un número para que alfabeto pueda usarlo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo el siguiente código

```
//Declaras todas tus variables
int índice = -1;

for(int i = 0; i<mensaje.length; i++)
{
    indice = alfabeto.IndexOf(mensaje.charAt(i));
    textoCifrado += llave.charAt(indice);
}

return textoCifrado;
```

Lo que hago aki es que recorro la variable mensaje caracter por caracter y en la variable índice guardo precisamente el índice que ocupa ese carácter en el alfabeto original. Posteriormente busco en llave el caracter que está en índice y así voy cifrando.

Revisa bien la parte de los substring ya que en Java las cadenas de texto empiezan en 0, por lo que substring(0,26) va a devolver 27 letras y no 26, para esto tienes q poner substring(0,25).

Analiza este código y adáptalo al tuyo

Comment: ya lo he intentado, pero aun me sigue mostrando el mismo error en:

            indice = alfabeto.IndexOf(mensaje[i]);
            textoCifrado += llave[indice];

Comment: Revisa ahora, lo que pasa es que en java para acceder una posición de una cadena se usa el método charAt